# PHP Namespaces in SoapHeader Child Nodes

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, soapheader

PHP SoapClient Headers. I'm having a problem getting the namespaces in child nodes. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$security = new stdClass;
$security->UsernameToken->Password = 'MyPassword';
$security->UsernameToken->Username = 'MyUsername';
$header[] = new SOAPHeader('http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd', 'Security', $security);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Here's the XML it generates:

```
<ns2:Security>
  <UsernameToken>
    <Password>MyPassword</Password>
    <Username>MyUsername</Username>
  </UsernameToken>
</ns2:Security>
```

Here's the XML I want it to generate:

```
<ns2:Security>
  <ns2:UsernameToken>
    <ns2:Password>MyPassword</ns2:Password>
    <ns2:Username>MyUsername</ns2:Username>
  </ns2:UsernameToken>
</ns2:Security>
```

I need to get the namespace reference into the UsernameToken, Password and Username nodes. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

[David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370430/david) has the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13477414/111755). And he is also right that it takes *way too much effort and thought*. Here's a variation that encapsulates the ugliness for anyone working this particular wsse security header.

**Clean client code**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://some-domain.com/service.wsdl');
$client->__setSoapHeaders(new WSSESecurityHeader('myUsername', 'myPassword'));
```

**And the implementation...**

```
class WSSESecurityHeader extends SoapHeader {

    public function __construct($username, $password)
    {
        $wsseNamespace = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
        $security = new SoapVar(
            array(new SoapVar(
                array(
                    new SoapVar($username, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Username', $wsseNamespace),
                    new SoapVar($password, XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Password', $wsseNamespace)
                ), 
                SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
                null, 
                null, 
                'UsernameToken', 
                $wsseNamespace
            )), 
            SOAP_ENC_OBJECT
        );
        parent::SoapHeader($wsseNamespace, 'Security', $security, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I used this but changed the password section to:
new SoapVar($password, XSD_STRING, 'type', 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText', 'Password', $wsseNamespace)),
Which gives you:
<ns3:Password xsi:type="ns4:type">yourpassword</ns3:Password>

Answer (score 13):

Figured it out. I used nested SoapVars and arrays.

```
$ns_s = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';
$node1 = new SoapVar('MyUsername', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Username', $ns_s);
$node2 = new SoapVar('MyPassword', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'Password', $ns_s);
$token = new SoapVar(array($node1,$node2), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'UsernameToken', $ns_s);
$security = new SoapVar(array($token), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'Security', $ns_s);
$header[] = new SOAPHeader($ns_s, 'Security', $security, false);
```

That took entirely too much effort and thought...